# Sharepoint Tasks Updating when Permissions are added?

Tags: permissions, alert, task-list

When a user is added to a permissions group on our sharepoint (version 2010), the actions on our sharepoint task list all have their due date automatically changed to one day later.  This results in thousands of updates being sent to users that their action item has been changed.  ALL tasks on the list are updated, even those that have been completed years ago.

The email notes that the person who changed the due date was the person who new membership was granted for.

Any idea on how to make this stop?  The result is mass confusion as thousands of emails get sent about action items from 3+ years ago.

I do not want to turn off notification emails because they are helpful for when people get assigned new actions.  I would like to resolve the root cause of the due dates being changed.

Thanks!